# how to insert breakline while using insertBefore

Tags: jquery

I am trying this jQuery

```
$("span:contains('abc')").insertBefore($("span:contains('def')"));
```

How to add a break line between these two elements. Right now my output is `def abc`.

I want output like

```
def
abc
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is ok, that you move element, not create it ?

Answer (score 1):

Right now you have this:

```
$("span:contains('abc')").insertBefore($("span:contains('def')"));
```

The result will be `abcdef` not `defabc` because `abc` will be inserted before `def`. Now you may add a `<br>` using something like this ([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hfg3va6v/)):

```
$("span:contains('abc')").insertBefore($("span:contains('def')")).after('<br>');
```

If it's not what you want then you may change the selection and also you may use `.before()`. You may also use this alternatively to achieve the desired result ([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hfg3va6v/1/)):

```
$("span:contains('abc')").insertAfter($("span:contains('def')")).before('<br>');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <span>abc</span>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("span:contains('abc')").before($("<span><b>def</b></span><br>"));
</script>
</html>
```